# Is it possible to create a NewGlobalRef from a Class in last Android versions?

Tags: c, android-studio, java-native-interface

I have import and tested this project:

https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/hello-jni

in  Android Studio and worked well.

But when I copy the code for another new project I have the follow error:

“Incompatible point types `jclass` and `jobject”

In this line:

```c
    g_ctx.mainActivityClz = (*env).NewGlobalRef(clz);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyO7T.png)

Is it not possible to use “NewGlobalRef”  to create a new reference for a class in more recent versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NewGlobalRef` always returns a `jobject` even though you're giving it a `jclass` (which is a subclass of `jobject`).

You can solve this warning by explicitly downcasting to `jclass`, either as

```
(jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(...)
```

or

```
static_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(...)
```